# Phone's touchscreen becomes unresponsive when charging

Tags: charging

I have a Samsung A12. When using a charger for the phone other than the manufacturer intended, it seems that the phone's screen just becomes unresponsive whenever it is charging. What could be the reason for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other chargers emit too much electromagnetic interference for the device to work.

They are cheaper as the may be missing components inside or not otherwise designed to bring common mode interference down to acceptable level for the touch screen to work.

It is possible that they emit interference that is within legal limits, and the phone can also withstand intreference within legal limits, but third party chargers may just emit interference that is just too much for the phone and charger from manufacturer suppresses more interference than legally needed to allow the phone to work.